# Should Anaconda be use to manage system python? Or, is it just to create an isolated environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I already have Python 2.7 installed in Windows. I have normally used pip to install packages. However, Pandas recommends using Anaconda and it appears that it has many benefits so I wanted to try it.

I installed miniconda and it just reinstalled Python under its own directory. Does Anaconda always duplicate the python libraries or can it be used to manage the system's python.

I use python to develop and also wanted to use Pandas to analyse data. However, I would like to avoid have two copies of Python. I want to have one python environment that is constant with all the packages that I intend to have. Otherwise, I feel that I will have to install the same packages multiple times.

I know that Anaconda is to separate different environments. Does this mean that I am trying to do something it is not its purpose or have I installed it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda has a root environment that includes a bit more than 100 of the most popular Python packages.

Yes, you can use the root Python as your system's Python executable.

The anaconda installation comes with Conda, which is a robust environment manager.  If you want to keep your root environment stable, you can use Conda to create new environments for each project, and Conda handles the dependencies of each environment as well.

You can create a new environment named "analysis" that has Python, IPython, and Pandas using:

```
conda create --name analysis python ipython pandas
```

After installing all of the packages, you can use the environment by running (from the CMD prompt):

```
conda activate analysis
```

Comment: I actually installed miniconda, so only have the packages I meant to install. I noticed that I have two environments by default: 1) Miniconda2 and base (root). However, when installing packages they appear under both. Is that how it is supposed to operate? Or, only packages that are different diverge?